# Undertand the number of users during and just before ramp-up period ends

Tags: jmeter

If I have a test plan that has a thread group with 1200 users and ramp-up period 60 seconds.  I have understood that 20 users will be added every second.  Does it mean that on the 60 seconds, I will have 1200 users doing the requests?  How many users will be doing their requests on the 60th seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on 3 factors:

1. The number of iterations in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. The number of [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in your Test Plan
3. Your application response time

If you configure Thread Group to loop `forever` - the answer is yes, you will have 1200 users doing the requests after 60 seconds. In the other case the answer will be different, you can check how many virtual users are/were online using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/))

Comment: I test for 5 and 10 loops, does this affect the number of users in the question? Does the number of loops affect the number of users.  So it executes the number of loops during the ramp-up period?

Comment: Measure it, we don't know the scenario duration for a single user/iteration. Check out [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected/)